# Enable alternative FTP port on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ftp, port

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 installed and using XLight FTP Server. I need to use 2221 port as FTP. I've created rules in FireWall, also run commands:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="FTP (non-SSL)" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=2221

netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp enable
```

FTP clients connect, but hangs on getting list of files and directories.

How to resolve that problem. Thank you!

Comment: Force a passive data channel instead?

Answer (score 2):

By default active FTP uses port 21 for control messages and 20 for data transfer and passive uses 21 for control and > 1023 for data transfer. The easiest way to resolve this in Windows is to use a program or service based rule instead of a port-based one.

Comment: I added this program to rule, it doesn't help, same problem, ftp client can't get list of files and folders

Comment: Have you restarted the FTP server service since adding the rule? Also, is the FTP client that you're using aware of your alternate port scheme?

Comment: Yes, I restarted FTP service of XLight FTP server and set up port 2221 in the XLight FTP server. I connect, but it hangs on on getting list of files and folders

Comment: I would try with another FTP server software see if it's related to a problem with "XLight FTP Server"